# Design: How to handle illegal console inputs with Scanner?

Tags: java, exception

From a design standpoint, what is the best way to handle illegal input from a user that is defined by the programmer.

Ex: I ask for a user to input quantity, but he inputs "fewfiejfjw".

Should I make a custom exception? Is there a commonly accepted exception to be thrown in this case? Or should I just say

```
if(!in.next().matches("\b\d+\b"){
System.out.print("Try again");
//..code to repeat method goes here
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should throw an exception. You should handle the input and show an error and ask the user to try again. No reason to stop the application.

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner` has a class of methods for checking whether the next token is a valid integer etc. For an example, see [`hasNextInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29). Call this before calling `nextInt()` etc.

What is the best way to handle invalid input really depends on your application. I guess it's not unreasonable to ask the user to enter the value again (of course, having skipped past the invalid token so that you don't create an infinite loop).